# Crystal: Cannot show page footer when using Fortmat with multiple columns in some pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Format with multiple columns and expand layout width for Detail section to show many columns. And when my report show data in the expand detail section, it do not show page footer.

Could you please help me fix it?

Please following [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rn0m4tzrhk9kusn/AskFotmatWithMultiColumns.7z) for more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your report setup is quite strange. Why don't you move your PO and Customer Name field next to ship date and get rid of the excess page? You can also delete your Page Header B, Group Header B and Details B since there is nothing in them. But if you have to keep the current layout, in order to see the footer on the other page you will have to add it to the other page, just like the Group Header above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally, I can show Page Footer by using Report Footer and create a new Detail like dump footer.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Please make sure to upvote or mark as answered if an answer was helpful to you or solved your problem. Thank you.